# Can't connect to SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server, firewall

I have configured SQL Server 13 to Allow Remote Connections, I've also enabled TCP/IP and verified the port specified is 1433. The computer running SQL server has the firewall disabled. I have forwarded port 1433 on my router. I can connect to the SQL server from another computer in the LAN, but not outside the LAN.

I tried changing the SQL Server TCP/IP listening port to 49172 and I was able to connect to the SQL server outside the LAN. Why can't I use port 1433? I've disabled every type of security option on my router. I have a Sophos UTM9 firewall/router.

Comment: I can only deduce that my ISP is blocking that port. I am using Rogers Business in Canada.

Comment: no idea what could be the reason, but have you tried forward WAN port 49172 to the server LAN port 1433 ?

Comment: That's a good idea.. I didn't think of that. But that didn't work either. So for now I have setup two different listening ports on my SQL server. Externally, I use 49172, internally I use 1433.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable telnet in your computer

This is for enabling telnet (Google source)

- Click Start > Control Panel.
- Click Programs and Features.
- Click Turn Windows features on or off.
- In the Windows Features dialog box, check the Telnet Client check
  box.
- Click OK. The system installs the appropriate files. This will take a
  few seconds to a minute.

Then on command prompt try

Telnet (ipnumber) 1433

if it connects your connection is working, if not that is the case and you have to disable your firewall.

Tell me how did it go

Good luck

Comment: It works from inside my LAN, but not outside my LAN.

Answer (score -1):

Check 1433 port is enabled or not.

Comment: Yes, its enabled.